unable to import a golang package from my public bitbucket repo
i am trying to import my golang client library.
folder structure
golang/
├── gms
│   ├── go.mod
│   └── src
│       ├── cmd
│       │   └── gms
│       │       └── main.go
│       └── pkg
│           ├── globals
│           │   ├── globals.go
│           │   └── logger.go
│           ├── httpclient
│           │   ├── client.go
│           │   └── struct.go
│           └── point
│               ├── point.go
│               └── struct.go
└── README.md

This is the content of my go.mod file
module bitbucket.company.com/users/rishavkumarj/gms-client-library/golang/gms

go 1.21.3

My code is present on the url https://bitbucket.company.com/bbdc/users/rishavkumarj/repos/gms-client-library/browse
But when I try to import the package, i am getting errors
rishavkumarj@go:~/fork/rishavkumarj/gms-client-library/golang/gms$ go get bitbucket.company.com/users/rishavkumarj/gms-client-library/golang/gms
go: bitbucket.company.com/users/rishavkumarj/gms-client-library/golang/gms: module bitbucket.company.com/users/rishavkumarj/gms-client-library/golang: reading https://artifactory.company.com/artifactory/api/go/zextgolangproxy-go-rel-virtual/bitbucket.company.com/users/rishavkumarj/gms-client-library/golang/@v/list: 404 

rishavkumarj@go:~/fork/rishavkumarj/gms-client-library/golang/gms$ GOPROXY="" go get bitbucket.company.com/users/rishavkumarj/gms-client-library/golang/gms
go: bitbucket.company.com/users/rishavkumarj/gms-client-library/golang/gms: unrecognized import path "bitbucket.company.com/users/rishavkumarj/gms-client-library/golang": parse https://bitbucket.company.com/users/rishavkumarj/gms-client-library/golang?go-get=1: no go-import meta tags (meta tag bitbucket.company.com/bbdc/users/rishavkumarj did not match import path bitbucket.company.com/users/rishavkumarj/gms-client-library/golang)


You should set the env var GOPRIVATE. Docs: https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Configuration_for_downloading_non_public_code

Looks like you are getting module from your own version control server with proxy https://artifactory.company.com/artifactory/api/go/zextgolangproxy-go-rel-virtual, try to set GOPRIVATE
export GOPRIVATE=bitbucket.company.com

and run go get again.
For more details:
https://go.dev/ref/mod#private-modules

I tried it, see the errors which I have posted below.

rishavkumarj@go:~/fork/rishavkumarj/gms-client-library/golang/gms$ GOPRIVATE='bitbucket.company.com' go get bitbucket.company.com/users/rishavkumarj/repos/gms-client-library/golang/gms/pkg/globals

error:
go: unrecognized import path "bitbucket.company.com/users/rishavkumarj/repos/gms-client-library/golang/gms/pkg/globals": parse https://bitbucket.company.com/users/rishavkumarj/repos/gms-client-library/golang/gms/pkg/globals?go-get=1: no go-import meta tags (meta tag bitbucket.company.com/bbdc/users/rishavkumarj did not match import path bitbucket.company.com/users/rishavkumarj/repos/gms-client-library/golang/gms/pkg/globals)
